# CSS columns, break only after divs, not every row

Tags: html, css

I have got this code

**HTML:**

```
<div id="tree">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony_c3265066.html">Smartphony</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-apple-ios_c3265067.html">Apple iOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-android_c3265068.html">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-odolne-smartphony_c14347802.html">Odolné smartphony</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-dual-sim-smartphony_c14347803.html">Dual SIM smartphony</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety_c1976100.html">Tablety</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-apple-ios_c3265076.html">Apple iOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-android_c3265077.html">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-detske-tablety_c5571743.html">Dětské tablety</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-outdoorove-mobily_c9586170.html">Outdoorové mobily</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily_c1521838.html">Klasické mobily</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-klasicke_c1702094.html">Klasické</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-stolni-telefony_c12458931.html">Stolní telefony</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-dual-sim_c1702093.html">Dual SIM</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-pro-seniory_c1702092.html">Pro seniory</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika_c5375549.html">Nositelná elektronika</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-fitness-naramky_c5380451.html">Fitness náramky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-chytre-hodinky_c5380452.html">Chytré hodinky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-krokomery_c19204240.html">Krokoměry</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-reminky_c14033999.html">Řemínky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-prislusenstvi_c8398823.html">Příslušenství</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-powerbanky_c5375550.html">Powerbanky</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce_c18082361.html">Kabely a redukce</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-usb-c-kabely_c18082362.html">USB-C kabely</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-usb-micro-kabely_c18082363.html">USB micro kabely</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-lightning-kabely_c18082364.html">Lightning kabely</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie_c3265092.html">Držáky, stativy a selfie</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-popsockets_c18689050.html">PopSockets</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-klasicke-drzaky_c18758583.html">Klasické držáky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-stativy-tripody-_c18689051.html">Stativy (tripody)</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-selfie-tyce_c18758580.html">Selfie tyče</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-do-ventilace_c18758581.html">Držáky do ventilace</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-na-operku-hlavy_c18758582.html">Držáky na opěrku hlavy</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-s-bezdratovym-nabijenim_c18770654.html">Držáky s bezdrátovým nabíjením</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-s-magnetickym-prichycenim_c18770655.html">Držáky s magnetickým přichycením</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-pro-tablety_c18770656.html">Držáky pro tablety</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety_c3265079.html">Příslušenství pro tablety</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-obaly-a-pouzdra_c3265081.html">Obaly a pouzdra</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-folie_c4875255.html">Fólie</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-nabijecky_c3265107.html">Nabíječky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-stylusy_c5518311.html">Stylusy</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-ostatni_c3265086.html">Ostatní</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony_c3265080.html">Příslušenství pro smartphony</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-obaly-a-pouzdra_c3265088.html">Obaly a pouzdra</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-kryty_c4875267.html">Kryty</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-folie_c4875256.html">Fólie</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-baterie_c4066086.html">Baterie</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-nabijecky_c3265108.html">Nabíječky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-dokovaci-stanice_c3265106.html">Dokovací stanice</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-ostatni_c3265093.html">Ostatní</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-gadgets_c5596462.html">Gadgets</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-handsfree_c9233118.html">Handsfree</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tree{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#tree ul{
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
#tree a{
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
#tree h4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 04px 0;
}
#tree h4 a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2576d1;
}
#tree > div{
    padding: 14px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}

#tree > div > div{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

It works almost perfect to set content into 3 columns but I want it to break after every `#tree > div > div` not after every element.

**Here is picture how it looks**
[image]

**And here is how it should look**
[image]

**Thank you and have a nice day**

Comment: Unless you have a need to support older versions of ie, I would recommend CSS Grid as a cleaner solution to this.

Comment: I tried CSS grid but it didnt stack the elements how I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The required result of 3 column layout can be achieved through these 4 steps:

**Step 1:** Define css classes for table, row and column

**Step 2:** Specify 3 column layout by making the column class occupy 33% of width

**Step 3:** Configure the row class to stack columns one below the other when there is not enough screen width

**Step 4:** Update HTML div elements with the table, row and column classes

**Here is the copy of working code that shows 3 columns with responsive design:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tree structure - demo</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">        
        <style>
            .my-table {
                border: 1px solid black;
                min-width: 180px;
            }

            .my-list{
                list-style-type: disc;
            }

            .heading4 {
                font-size: 16px;
                color: #2576d1;
            }

            .my-column {
                float: left;
                width: 33%;
                min-width: 150px;
            }

            .my-row:after {
                content: "";
                display: table;
                clear: both;
            }


        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tree" class="my-table">
            <div class="my-row">
                <div class="my-column">
                  <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony_c3265066.html">Smartphony</a></h4>
                  <ul class="my-list">
                    <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-apple-ios_c3265067.html">Apple iOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-android_c3265068.html">Android</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-odolne-smartphony_c14347802.html">Odolné smartphony</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-dual-sim-smartphony_c14347803.html">Dual SIM smartphony</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="my-column">
                  <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety_c1976100.html">Tablety</a></h4>
                  <ul class="my-list">
                    <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-apple-ios_c3265076.html">Apple iOS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-android_c3265077.html">Android</a></li>
                    <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-detske-tablety_c5571743.html">Dětské tablety</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="my-column">
                  <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-outdoorove-mobily_c9586170.html">Outdoorové mobily</a></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-row">
                <div class="my-column">
                    <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily_c1521838.html">Klasické mobily</a></h4>
                    <ul class="my-list">
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-klasicke_c1702094.html">Klasické</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-stolni-telefony_c12458931.html">Stolní telefony</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-dual-sim_c1702093.html">Dual SIM</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-pro-seniory_c1702092.html">Pro seniory</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="my-column">
                    <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika_c5375549.html">Nositelná elektronika</a></h4>
                    <ul class="my-list">
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-fitness-naramky_c5380451.html">Fitness náramky</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-chytre-hodinky_c5380452.html">Chytré hodinky</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-krokomery_c19204240.html">Krokoměry</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-reminky_c14033999.html">Řemínky</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-prislusenstvi_c8398823.html">Příslušenství</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="my-column">
                    <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-powerbanky_c5375550.html">Powerbanky</a></h4>
                  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="my-row">
                <div class="my-column">
                    <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce_c18082361.html">Kabely a redukce</a></h4>
                    <ul class="my-list">
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-usb-c-kabely_c18082362.html">USB-C kabely</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-usb-micro-kabely_c18082363.html">USB micro kabely</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-lightning-kabely_c18082364.html">Lightning kabely</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="my-column">
                    <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie_c3265092.html">Držáky, stativy a selfie</a></h4>
                    <ul class="my-list">
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-popsockets_c18689050.html">PopSockets</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-klasicke-drzaky_c18758583.html">Klasické držáky</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-stativy-tripody-_c18689051.html">Stativy (tripody)</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-selfie-tyce_c18758580.html">Selfie tyče</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-do-ventilace_c18758581.html">Držáky do ventilace</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-na-operku-hlavy_c18758582.html">Držáky na opěrku hlavy</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-s-bezdratovym-nabijenim_c18770654.html">Držáky s bezdrátovým nabíjením</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-s-magnetickym-prichycenim_c18770655.html">Držáky s magnetickým přichycením</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-pro-tablety_c18770656.html">Držáky pro tablety</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="my-column">
                    <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety_c3265079.html">Příslušenství pro tablety</a></h4>
                    <ul class="my-list">
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-obaly-a-pouzdra_c3265081.html">Obaly a pouzdra</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-folie_c4875255.html">Fólie</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-nabijecky_c3265107.html">Nabíječky</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-stylusy_c5518311.html">Stylusy</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-ostatni_c3265086.html">Ostatní</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>                
            </div>
            <div class="my-row">
                <div class="my-column">
                    <h4 class="heading4"><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony_c3265080.html">Příslušenství pro smartphony</a></h4>
                    <ul class="my-list">
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-obaly-a-pouzdra_c3265088.html">Obaly a pouzdra</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-kryty_c4875267.html">Kryty</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-folie_c4875256.html">Fólie</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-baterie_c4066086.html">Baterie</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-nabijecky_c3265108.html">Nabíječky</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-dokovaci-stanice_c3265106.html">Dokovací stanice</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-ostatni_c3265093.html">Ostatní</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-gadgets_c5596462.html">Gadgets</a></li>
                      <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-handsfree_c9233118.html">Handsfree</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, I made the other changes required to css and html and updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to set `display: inline-block` to your `#tree > div > div`to keep them all together.

```css
#tree{
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
#tree ul{
    list-style-type: disc;
    margin-left: 18px;
}
#tree a{
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.6;
}
#tree h4 {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 04px 0;
}
#tree h4 a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #2576d1;

}
#tree > div{
    padding: 14px 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}

#tree > div > div{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="tree">
  <div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony_c3265066.html">Smartphony</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-apple-ios_c3265067.html">Apple iOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-android_c3265068.html">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-odolne-smartphony_c14347802.html">Odolné smartphony</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-smartphony-dual-sim-smartphony_c14347803.html">Dual SIM smartphony</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety_c1976100.html">Tablety</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-apple-ios_c3265076.html">Apple iOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-android_c3265077.html">Android</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-tablety-detske-tablety_c5571743.html">Dětské tablety</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-outdoorove-mobily_c9586170.html">Outdoorové mobily</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily_c1521838.html">Klasické mobily</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-klasicke_c1702094.html">Klasické</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-stolni-telefony_c12458931.html">Stolní telefony</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-dual-sim_c1702093.html">Dual SIM</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-klasicke-mobily-pro-seniory_c1702092.html">Pro seniory</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika_c5375549.html">Nositelná elektronika</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-fitness-naramky_c5380451.html">Fitness náramky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-chytre-hodinky_c5380452.html">Chytré hodinky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-krokomery_c19204240.html">Krokoměry</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-reminky_c14033999.html">Řemínky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-nositelna-elektronika-prislusenstvi_c8398823.html">Příslušenství</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-powerbanky_c5375550.html">Powerbanky</a></h4>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce_c18082361.html">Kabely a redukce</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-usb-c-kabely_c18082362.html">USB-C kabely</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-usb-micro-kabely_c18082363.html">USB micro kabely</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-kabely-a-redukce-lightning-kabely_c18082364.html">Lightning kabely</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie_c3265092.html">Držáky, stativy a selfie</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-popsockets_c18689050.html">PopSockets</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-klasicke-drzaky_c18758583.html">Klasické držáky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-stativy-tripody-_c18689051.html">Stativy (tripody)</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-selfie-tyce_c18758580.html">Selfie tyče</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-do-ventilace_c18758581.html">Držáky do ventilace</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-na-operku-hlavy_c18758582.html">Držáky na opěrku hlavy</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-s-bezdratovym-nabijenim_c18770654.html">Držáky s bezdrátovým nabíjením</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-s-magnetickym-prichycenim_c18770655.html">Držáky s magnetickým přichycením</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-drzaky-stativy-a-selfie-drzaky-pro-tablety_c18770656.html">Držáky pro tablety</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety_c3265079.html">Příslušenství pro tablety</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-obaly-a-pouzdra_c3265081.html">Obaly a pouzdra</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-folie_c4875255.html">Fólie</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-nabijecky_c3265107.html">Nabíječky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-stylusy_c5518311.html">Stylusy</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-tablety-ostatni_c3265086.html">Ostatní</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony_c3265080.html">Příslušenství pro smartphony</a></h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-obaly-a-pouzdra_c3265088.html">Obaly a pouzdra</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-kryty_c4875267.html">Kryty</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-folie_c4875256.html">Fólie</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-baterie_c4066086.html">Baterie</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-nabijecky_c3265108.html">Nabíječky</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-dokovaci-stanice_c3265106.html">Dokovací stanice</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-ostatni_c3265093.html">Ostatní</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-gadgets_c5596462.html">Gadgets</a></li>
        <li><a href="tablety-telefony-prislusenstvi-pro-smartphony-handsfree_c9233118.html">Handsfree</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you seen it on full screen?

Comment: I tried inline-block but if you check your code in fullscreen, it doesnt keep 3 columns. https://i.imgur.com/CJVc1bq.png

Comment: Ahhh, understood. I'll look into it some more.